# How to plot the function the absolute value of abs(x)^3-abs(x) using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot the function abs(x)^3-abs(x), in tikpicture framework, but the run file gave me wrong graph.

Comment: You aren't providing any code, so how do you expect us to guess what you're doing and what could be wrong? Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: The correct solution is to mever use `x^3` when you mean `x*x*x`.

Answer (score 3):

Hey and welcome to TeX SE, I understand you're new here and you passed the given tutorial in the beginning quickly, but one of the important rules here is to provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), but that's okay (at least for me) :

TikZ package provides a nice command to plot functions, which as you might have guessed `plot`, and we use it as follows to draw the plot of your function :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=30mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} %you can skip this line since I already declared TikZ before (but my guess is you'll copy this without reading it)
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[->] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[above] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2)--(0,5) node[left] {$y$};
\draw[thick, blue, samples=300, variable=\t, domain=-1.8:1.8] plot(\t,{(abs(\t))^3-abs(\t)}) node[right] {$(\mathcal{C}_f)$};
\node[blue] at (3.5,-1) {$f : x\longmapsto \vert x\vert^3 -\vert x\vert$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result :

[image]

Have a nice day !